# How to detect collision between circle and rotating polygon with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision

My program begins by drawing an n-sided polygon with circles inside it, like this: [initial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oWyy.png). The polygon is continuously rotating around its center, and the circles have incredibly simple physics to fall down with gravity and bounce when they hit a wall.

However, I am having trouble detecting when the circles have hit a wall. Here is my current collision detection method, which involves finding the minimum distance from the line to the circle and comparing it to the circle's radius:

```
function collisionDetector(ball){
//calculate distance from all sides of the polygon
for(var i = 0; i < currentPolyPointsX.length -1; i++){
    //get coordinates of line end points
    let x1 = currentPolyPointsX[i];
    let x2 = currentPolyPointsX[i+1];
    let y1 = currentPolyPointsY[i];
    let y2 = currentPolyPointsY[i+1];
    //calculate length of line
    let distanceX = x1 - x2;
    let distanceY = y1 - y2;
    let length = Math.sqrt( (distanceX *distanceX) + (distanceY*distanceY) );
    //calculate dot product of vectors from line ends and ball
    let dot = ( ((ball.x - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((ball.y - y1) * (y2-y1)) ) 
                    / Math.pow(length, 2);
    //calculate x and y coordinate on line (extends to infinity) closest to ball
    let closestX = x1 + (dot * (x2 - x1));
    let closestY = y1 + (dot * (y2 - y1));
    //if those coordinates are not currently on our line, return false
    if(!onLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, closestX, closestY)){
        return false;
    }
    //calculate distance from closest coordinates to ball
    distanceX = closestX - ball.x;
    distanceY = closestY - ball.y;
    let distance = Math.sqrt( (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY) );
    //if the ball is less than/equal to one radius away, it has collided
    if( distance <= ball.returnRadius() ){
        return true;
    }else{ 
        return false;
     }
  }

}
```

The points of the polygon are pushed into parallel arrays by this code:

```
function drawPolygon() { //x&y are positions, side is side number, r is size
    //get current values of canvas center
    var x = canvas.width /2;
    var y = canvas.height /2;
    var r = canvas.width /2;
    //draw {sides} sided polygon
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo (x + r * Math.cos(0), y + r *  Math.sin(0));
    //clear currently stored points
    currentPolyPointsX.length = 0;
    currentPolyPointsY.length = 0;
    //draw and save new polygon points in array
    for (var i = 1; i <= sides; i ++) {
        ctx.lineTo (x + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides), 
            y + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides));
        currentPolyPointsX.push(x + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides)); // <----
        currentPolyPointsY.push(y + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides)); // <----
    }
    //draw the polygon
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.save();
}
```

And then modified to reflect current rotation by this code:

```
function rotatePolygon(x){
    let centerX = canvas.height/2;
    let centerY = canvas.height/2;
    let angle = x * Math.PI / 180
    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //move rotation point to center of canvas
    ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
    //rotate around center of canvas
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    //move back to origin
    ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
    //draw rotated polygon
    drawPolygon();
    //adjust coordinates to match rotation
    let cos = Math.cos(x * Math.PI / 180);
    let sin = Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 180);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < currentPolyPointsX.length; i++){                    // <----
        currentPolyPointsX[i] = ((cos * (currentPolyPointsX[i] - centerX)) // <----
             - (sin * (currentPolyPointsY[i] - centerY)) + centerX);       // <----
        currentPolyPointsY[i] = ((cos * (currentPolyPointsY[i] - centerY)) // <----
        + (sin * (currentPolyPointsX[i] - centerX)) + centerY);            // <----
    }
    //un-rotate
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(-x * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.width/2);    
}
```

For whatever reason, this only detects collision between one of the polygon's walls, which doesn't make sense to me because it is capturing all the polygon's points and should be comparing them all to the circle's positions. This is a snippet of the console output for the parallel arrays:

```
X values: 100.26987463346667,2.871334680692655,162.69628391854758,358.87207475054254,320.2904320167505
Y values: 250.03751023155084,132.28082275846333,92.90811041924998,186.33112343743124,283.44243315330453
```

What am I doing wrong? No matter how I fiddle with the code, it only ever detects one wall. Even when rotation is turned off. Even when the number of sides is changed. Even when the speed of rotation as well as the speed of gravity are adjusted. It is driving me nuts! Any help you all provide will be greatly appreciated.

Here is a full snippet of the code in question. If you play with rotation speed, it helps to see which side is operational.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let rotationSlider = document.getElementById("rotationSlider");
let sidesSlider = document.getElementById("sidesSlider");
//# sided polygon to draw
let sides = 5;
let speed = 33;
let rotationIncrement = 1;
let sideLength = 0;
//stores current corner coordinates for polygon
let currentPolyPointsX = [];
let currentPolyPointsY = [];

const GRAVITY = 1;

const Ball = {

  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  vector: [0, 0],
  speed: 0,
  gravity: 1,
  //returns the ball's radius, which is set according to canvas height
  returnRadius: function() {

    return canvas.height * 0.01;
  }
}

let ballHolder = [];

function startup() {
  resizeCanvas();
  main();
  ballInit(10);
  sideLengthInit();
}

function main() {
  //get center coordinates of canvas
  var center = canvas.width / 2;
  //pass desired size, and center coords (x,y) to drawHexagon
  rotationLoop();
  ballLoop();


  setTimeout(main, speed);
}

function ballInit(amount) {
  //clear any residual balls
  ballHolder = [];
  //initialize array of objects with {amount} of balls and give each a random jitter
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    ballHolder.push(Object.create(Ball));
    ballHolder[i].x = canvas.height / 2 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
    ballHolder[i].y = canvas.height / 2 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
  }

}

//calculated distance between two points via distance formula
function distanceCalc(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
}

function ballLoop() {
  //draw each ball on the canvas, and calculate bounce + collision with container
  ballHolder.forEach(ball => {
    //calculate gravity
    ball.y = gravityCalc(ball);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc((ball.x), (ball.y), canvas.height * 0.01, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();

    //check for collision
    if (collisionDetector(ball)) {
      //calculate bounce if collision occurs
      ball.gravity = ball.gravity * -1;
    }

    //console.log("ball " + ball.x + " " + ball.y);
  });
}

function gravityCalc(ball) {

  return ball.y + (GRAVITY * ball.gravity);
}

function sideLengthInit() {
  sideLength = distanceCalc(currentPolyPointsX[0], currentPolyPointsY[0],
    currentPolyPointsX[1], currentPolyPointsY[1])

}


function collisionDetector(ball) {

  //calculate distance from all sides of the polygon
  for (var i = 0; i < currentPolyPointsX.length - 1; i++) {
    //get coordinates of line end points
    let x1 = currentPolyPointsX[i];
    let x2 = currentPolyPointsX[i + 1];
    let y1 = currentPolyPointsY[i];
    let y2 = currentPolyPointsY[i + 1];
    //calculate length of line
    let distanceX = x1 - x2;
    let distanceY = y1 - y2;
    let length = Math.sqrt((distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY));
    //calculate dot product of vectors from line ends and ball
    let dot = (((ball.x - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((ball.y - y1) * (y2 - y1))) /
      Math.pow(length, 2);
    //calculate x and y coordinate on line (extends to infinity) closest to ball
    let closestX = x1 + (dot * (x2 - x1));
    let closestY = y1 + (dot * (y2 - y1));
    //if those coordinates are not currently on our line, return false
    if (!onLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, closestX, closestY)) {
      return false;
    }
    //calculate distance from closest coordinates to ball
    distanceX = closestX - ball.x;
    distanceY = closestY - ball.y;
    let distance = Math.sqrt((distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY));
    //if the ball is less than/equal to one radius away, it has collided
    if (distance <= ball.returnRadius()) {
      /*console.log("COLLISION: " + ball.x + " " + ball.y + " " + closestX + " " + closestY + " " +
          "\n " + distance + "\n " + currentPolyPointsX + "\n " + currentPolyPointsY);*/
      return true;

    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}

function onLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, px, py) {
  let length = distanceCalc(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  let distance1 = distanceCalc(px, py, x1, y1);
  let distance2 = distanceCalc(px, py, x2, y2);
  let buffer = 1;
  return (distance1 + distance2 >= length - buffer && distance1 + distance2 <= length + buffer);

}

let rotationAmount = 0;

function rotationLoop() {

  if (rotationAmount < 360) {
    rotationAmount += parseInt(rotationIncrement);
  }
  if (rotationAmount >= 360) {
    rotationAmount = 0;
  }

  rotatePolygon(rotationAmount);

}

function drawPolygon() { //x&y are positions, side is side number, r is size, color is to fill
  //get current values of canvas center
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var r = canvas.width / 2;
  //draw {sides} sided polygon
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + r * Math.cos(0), y + r * Math.sin(0));
  //clear currently stored points
  currentPolyPointsX.length = 0;
  currentPolyPointsY.length = 0;
  //draw and save new polygon points in array
  for (var i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides), y + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides));
    currentPolyPointsX.push(x + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides));
    currentPolyPointsY.push(y + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sides));
  }
  //draw the polygon
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.save();

  //console.log("drawn " + x + " " + y + " " + sides + " " + r);
}

function rotatePolygon(x) {
  let centerX = canvas.height / 2;
  let centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  let angle = x * Math.PI / 180
  //clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //move rotation point to center of canvas
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  //rotate around center of canvas
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  //move back to origin
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
  //draw rotated polygon
  drawPolygon();
  //adjust coordinates to match rotation
  let cos = Math.cos(x * Math.PI / 180);
  let sin = Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 180);

  for (let i = 0; i < currentPolyPointsX.length; i++) {
    currentPolyPointsX[i] = ((cos * (currentPolyPointsX[i] - centerX)) -
      (sin * (currentPolyPointsY[i] - centerY)) + centerX);
    currentPolyPointsY[i] = ((cos * (currentPolyPointsY[i] - centerY)) +
      (sin * (currentPolyPointsX[i] - centerX)) + centerY);

  }
  /*console.log("X values: " + currentPolyPointsX + "\n" +
      "Y values: " + currentPolyPointsY);*/

  //un-rotate
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(-x * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.width / 2);

  //console.log("rotated " + x);


}

function resizeCanvas() {
  //gather window dimensions
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var width = window.innerWidth;

  //if dimensions are portrait, resize canvas based on height
  if (height < width) {
    var canvasSquared = window.innerHeight * .8 + "px";
  } else { //if dimensions are landscape/square, resize canvas based on width
    var canvasSquared = window.innerWidth * .8 + "px";
  }

  //commit canvas dimensions
  canvas.height = parseFloat(canvasSquared);
  canvas.style.height = canvasSquared;
  canvas.width = parseFloat(canvasSquared);
  canvas.style.width = canvasSquared;

  //draw new hexagon of appropriate size
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawPolygon();
  console.log("resized: " + canvasSquared + " width : " + canvas.width + " height: " + canvas.height);
}

rotationSlider.oninput = () => rotationIncrement = rotationSlider.value;
sidesSlider.oninput = () => sides = sidesSlider.value;
window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mainCanvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.5em grey;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Gravity Synth</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Sounds Go Bonk">
  <meta name="author" content="D.A.">

  <meta property="og:title" content="Sounds Go Bonk">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Sounds Go Bonk">
  <!--
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body onload="startup()">

  <canvas id="mainCanvas" class="mainCanvas"></canvas>
  <div>Speed</div>
  <input type="range" min=0 max=5 value=1 class="slider" id="rotationSlider">
  <div>Sides</div>
  <input type="range" min=3 max=9 value=5 class="slider" id="sidesSlider">

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your last `if` in `collisionDetector` always terminates the function since it always causes a `return` no matter the outcome. This means only the first line will ever be checked.

Comment: @Ouroborus you are absolutely right! Thank you for noticing that. Sadly, even when I remove the `else{ return false}` it still behaves the same-- only one side seems to detect collision.

Comment: That first `return false` in the `onLine` check in `collisionDetector` should probably be a `continue`. You don't want to exit yet, you want to continue to the next iteration of the loop to check the next line.

Comment: @Ouroborus bless your soul. That worked like a charm! Now it is calculating collision for every side. Thank you so much for your help; I spent hours trying to work that out myself. While you were looking around, did you by chance notice something wrong with my `rotatePolygon()` function? When I disable the `for` loop in that function then the program calculates collision correctly for a static polygon and works beautifully, but when the `for` loop is on then the circles register collision randomly in empty space.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it might be because you're using both canvas transforms and computed transforms on the same things.